# Android - save/restore state of custom class

Tags: java, android, ssh, bundle, state

I have some class for ssh support - it uses jsch internally. I use this class on main activity, this way:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

 SshSupport ssh = new SshSupport();

.....

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    //Handle events for ssh
    ssh.eventHandler = new ISshEvents()
    {


        @Override
        public void SshCommandExecuted(SshCommandsEnum commandType, String result)
        {

        }

      //other overrides here


    }

        //Ssh operations on gui item click 
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3)
        {

            if (ssh.IsConnected() == false)
            {
                try
                {

                    ssh.ConnectAsync(/*parameters*/);

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            try
            {
                ssh.ExecuteCommandAsync(SshCommandsEnum.values()[position]);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

}
```

It works very well. My application connects to ssh, performs all needed operation in background thread and results are reported to gui, via events as shown above. But nothing works after user change device orientation. It's clear for me - activity is re-created and all state is lost. Unfortunately, my SshSupport class object is lost as well.

It's pretty easy to store gui state for dynamically changed/added objects (using put/get serializable etc methods). But I have no idea how to prevent my ssh object, ssh connected session being lost.

Since my class is not serializable, I can't save it to bundle. Also, even if I make my SshSupport class serializable, jsch objects it uses still are not serializable.

So what is the best way to solve this? Also, I need to perform some background operations (using AsyncTask inside my SshSupport class). And progress should be reported to MainActivity. But again, my thread will be destroyed on device orientation change.

[added]
Regarding to your solution, I created retained fragment and handled it this way:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    SshSupport ssh;
    private RetainedFragment dataFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // find the retained fragment on activity restarts
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        dataFragment = (RetainedFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("data");

        // create the fragment and data the first time
        if (dataFragment == null)
        {
            ssh = new SshSupport();

            // add the fragment
            dataFragment = new RetainedFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(dataFragment, "data").commit();
            // load the data from the web
            dataFragment.setData(ssh);
        }

        ssh = dataFragment.getData();

        ssh.eventHandler = new ISshEvents()
        {

           .......

        }



   }

     @Override
    public void onDestroy()
     {
        super.onDestroy();
        // store the data in the fragment
        dataFragment.setData(ssh);
     }
}
```

Is this correct? It seems to work as should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So what is the best way to solve this?

Use a retained fragment to manage your SSH connection. By "retained fragment", I mean one on which you have called `setRetainInstance(true)`. That fragment will not be destroyed and recreated on the configuration change. Instead, it will be "retained" and handed directly to the new activity instance, and so anything it holds onto is similarly retained.

It is safest if this fragment is one without a UI, added via a `FragmentTransaction`, though done carefully, you can add this behavior to an existing dynamic fragment.

You can read more about this in [the online documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject).

Comment: So if I understand correctly documentation example. Should I push created ssh object to setData in above sample? Ok, but how to handle my events? Should I assign events only once, before I put my object to fragment? I mean event overrides

Comment: @user1209216: "Should I push created ssh object to setData in above sample?" -- you should hold onto your "created ssh object" in a data member of the fragment. Whether you use getters and setters is up to you. "Should I assign events only once, before I put my object to fragment?" -- presumably.

Comment: @user1209216: From the standpoint of retaining your connection across the configuration change, this should work. Personally, I would just move all SSH-related logic into the fragment, for better code encapsulation.